# Python Search Function

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a list of number (forbidden number) where this number must be excluded:

```
a =  [10,21,25,28,29,30,31,55,70,80,95]
```

And I have a function that tells I can pick up a random number, but if this particular number is in a, then it must be added with 1.

```
def new_number(number):
    if number in a:
       new_number = number + 1
    else:
       new_number = number
    
    return new_number
```

This function is simple and working fine, but surely I will get a wrong result if I have consecutive number in a. For example if I enter number = 28, then the new number from the function is 29 while the correct one must be 32 because 29,30,31 are forbidden number.

I am looking for a function that can search the next valid number when there is consecutive invalid items and these invalid items can be flexibly changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `while` loop

**Ex:**

```
def new_number(number):
    a =  [10,21,25,28,29,30,31,55,70,80,95]
    while number in a:
        number += 1
    return number

print(new_number(28))     #32
print(new_number(400))    #400
```

Answer (score 3):

Using recursion (the [while loop approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63030933/7505395) is more performant if you use sets as well):

```
a =  {10,21,25,28,29,30,31,55,70,80,95}  # set is faster

def new_number(number):
    if number in a:
       return new_number(number + 1)

    return number  

print(new_number(28))     # 32
print(new_number(400))    # 400
```